# Autocomplete in TeXstudio for macro with optional argument

Tags: macros, texstudio, optional-arguments, auto-completion

I have a macro, such as

```
\newcommand*{\example}[2][]{#1.#2}
```

defined. TeXstudio adds this to its autocomplete list, which is great, but when I actually autocomplete it shows up as `\example{arg1}{arg2}`.
This is problematic, as I need to manually change the first pair of braces to square brackets. I would prefer either `[]{}` or simply just `{}`.

How do I change the behaviour of TeXstudio?

I'm using TeXstudio 2.6.6.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Which version of TXS are you using?

Comment: @TimHoffmann I added the information. I realize now, I've been not getting updates and may try updating from [https://launchpad.net/~blahota/+archive/ubuntu/texstudio/]